# Woocommerce product summary shortcode

Tags: woocommerce, shortcode, hook-woocommerce

I`m not lazy and did search to achieve this on my own but failed. I want to create a shortcode for woocomerce single product to display the product summary. I am wondering if you know how this can be achieved. Thanks

Comment: What is mean by product summary?

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will create a shortcode that is used like this:
`[product_description product_id="633"]`

```
/**
 * Register product_description shortcode
 * 
 * @param array $atts 'product_id' is the only supported attribute
 * 
 */
function kia_woo_short_description( $atts ) {

    if( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt' ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'product_id' => 0
    ), $atts, 'product_description' );

    global $post;
    $backup_post    = $post;

    // If not the current post store then temporarily override the $post object.
    if( 0 < $atts['product_id'] ) {
        $post = get_post( $atts['product_id']);

    }

    // Get the short description template:
    ob_start();
    woocommerce_template_single_excerpt();
    $html = ob_get_clean();

    // Restore original $post object.
    $post    = $backup_post;

    return $html;


}
add_shortcode( 'product_description', 'kia_woo_short_description' );
```